# Online and offline synchronization

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

I am working on a project that synchronizes online and offline features due to the unstable Internet. I have come up with a possible solution. That is to create 2 similar databases for both online and offline and sync the two. My question is that is this a good method? Or are there better options?

I have researched online on the subject but I haven't come across anything substantive. One useful link I found was on database Replication. But I want the offline version to detect Internet presence and sync accordingly.

Pls can you help me find solutions or clues to solve my problem?

Comment: MySQL replication is probably the best solution http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you have an online storage for syncing and a local database(browser indexeddb, program sqllite or something similar) and log all your changes in your local database but have a record with what data was entered after last sync.

When you have a connection you sync all new data with the online storage at set intervals(like once every 5 mins or constant stream if you have the bandwidth/cpu capacity)

When the user logs in from a "fresh" location the online database pushes all data to the client who fills the local database with the data and then it resumes normal syncing function.

Comment: Michael, I really appreciate your reply. It sounds great but can u pls elaborate further?

Comment: You have not provided code, posted a generic question and you expect a detailed answer? Everything you need to know is in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Plan A:  Primary-Primary replication (formerly called Master-Master).  You do need to be careful `PRIMARY KEYs` and `UNIQUE` keys.  While the "other" machine is offline, you could write conflicting values to a table.  Later, when they try to sync up, replication will freeze, requiring manual intervention.  (Not a pretty sight.)

Plan B:  Write changes to some storage other than the db.  This suffers the same drawbacks as Plan A, plus there is a bunch of coding on your part to implement it.

Plan C:  Galera cluster with 3 nodes.  When all 3 nodes are up, all can take writes.  If one node goes down, *or network problems make it seem offline to the other two*, it will automatically become read-only.  After things get fixed, the sync is done automatically.

Plan D:  Only write to a reliable Primary; let the other be a readonly Replica.  (But this violates your requirement about an "unstable Internet".)

None of these perfectly fits the requirements.  Plan A seems to be the only one that has a chance.  Let's look at that.

If you have any `UNIQUE` key in any table and you might insert new rows into it, the problem exists.  Even something as innocuous as a 'normalization table' wherein you insert a `name` and get back an `id` for use in other tables has the problem.  You might do that on both servers with the same `name` and get different `ids`.  Now you have a mess that is virtually impossible to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its outside the scope of the project but you can try these:

https://pouchdb.com/

https://couchdb.apache.org/

" PouchDB is an open-source JavaScript database inspired by Apache CouchDB that is designed to run well within the browser.

PouchDB was created to help web developers build applications that work as well offline as they do online.
It enables applications to store data locally while offline, then synchronize it with CouchDB and compatible servers when the application is back online, keeping the user's data in sync no matter where they next login. "